# Emails from my server are delivered to spam

Tags: email, postfix, spam

I have virtual server (Amazon EC2).

Emails from it (postfix) are sent into spam folders to some of the email services. And they are not sent to some emails (including some addresses on gmail).

There is no IP and hostname in spamhaus blacklists.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reasons you've discovered, it is futile to send out SMTP directly from EC2 instances.

Instead, either use Amazon's SES product for mail relay, or some other third party. SES is very cheap (or free for small to moderate email volumes) and quite easy to set up. They have documentation for all the major MTAs (sendmail, postfix, exim).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to EEAA, SES also allows secure smtp relay using stunnel which could be benefit if you have any security concern.